# Neo4j 2.0: SKIP, LIMIT, ORDER all results returned by UNION?

Tags: neo4j

I've got three queries that are combined with a UNION clause:

```
CYPHER 2.0
START user=node:User(Id="2")
MATCH (user)-[:FOLLOWS_USER]->()-[:SHARES]->(post)-[?:ORIGINAL]->(original)
WHERE original is null
RETURN distinct post.Id AS Id, post.CreationTime AS CreationTime
UNION
MATCH (user)-[:FOLLOWS_USER]->()-[:LIKES]->(post)
WITH post, count(post) as likes
WHERE likes >= 0
RETURN distinct post.Id AS Id, post.CreationTime AS CreationTime
UNION
MATCH (user)-[:FOLLOWS_USER]->()-[:SHARES]->(post)-[repost:ORIGINAL]->()
WITH post, count(repost) as reposts
WHERE reposts >= 0
RETURN distinct post.Id AS Id, post.CreationTime AS CreationTime
ORDER BY post.CreationTime desc
SKIP 0
LIMIT 100;
```

I want the `SKIP`, the `LIMIT` and the `ORDER BY` to apply to the **whole** result set, instead of the individual queries. I believe that's also the way it works in SQL. I think, however, that this is not the case in Neo4j, since I can just drop `desc` from the `ORDER BY` and the order remains the same.

Is this the intended behaviour? Is there a way I can write the query so that I can apply the `SKIP`, the `LIMIT` and the `ORDER BY`to the whole result set?

I'm also not sure if I have to repeat the line `START user=node:User(Id="2")` in each of the subqueries, since a query in 2.0 can start without a START clause. Do I have to repeat it?

Neo4j documentation is bit vague on the `UNION` keyword, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not yet supported, since before that there needs to be support for subqueries in order to implement things correctly.

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate. At least I can send multiple queries in a single HTTP request. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What is the status on post-UNION processing so that SKIP, LIMIT, ORDER BY works on the whole result set instead of the individual queries?